# Express router GET endpoint gives Not Found error

Tags: node.js, express, express-router, serverless-offline

This is my app.js

```
app.use('/v1/abc/', router);
```

Then secondary level

```
router.use('/:primary_id/def',defServices);
```

Final service level

```
     class defServices {
      constructor() {
        const router = new express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
        router.get('/', this.func1);
        router.get('/:pid',this.func2);
        router.put('/', this.func3);
  
        return router;
      }
    
      async func1(req, res) {
     //code goes here 
     }
  }

export default new defServices();
```

My request

```
GET  http://localhost:3000/dev/v1/abc/48/def
```

I'm having an issue with the first GET endpoint not reaching and getting 404 responses, but the second, GET endpoint and third PUT endpoint works fine. Furthermore, this implemented in serverless-offline

Comment: Could you please add your  http request? Most part of those kind of problems have relation with the request was executed.

Comment: i added the request